# DisplayPort to DVI not working on Quadro FX 580

Tags: windows-xp, graphics-card, displayport, nvidia-graphics-card

I have a PNY NVIDIA Quadro FX 580 graphics card with 1x DVI and 2x DisplayPorts. The DVI port works fine with both my Viewsonic monitors but I cannot get either of the DPs to work using the supplied DP to DVI adapter; all I get is a "no signal" on either monitor when connected to either DP port.

The manual states ( 2 out of 3 active at a time ), so a second monitor should work.

The NVIDIA Control Panel shows that the second monitor is not connected when in fact it is.

How do I get the second monitor to work?

System:

- Windows XP Professional 32-bit
- Asus P5Q motherboard
- Core 2 Duo E8500 CPU
- 4GB PC8500 RAM

Comment: Which viewsonic monitor are you using? Does it expect an analog signal on the DVI Plug or a digital one? Which resolution are you using (some unpowered adapters only allow low resolutions E.g. below 1920x1200, so test again with something silly like 1280x1024).

Answer (score 0):

I've heard "loosely" in a graphics card video review that some cards can only utilise one type of interface at a given time, i.e. you can't use DVI and Display Port connectors at the same time.

So, check the manual to see if there are any information that reads along these lines.

Comment: The manual states that any two DVI and/or DP connections can be connected at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide details on the monitors?  I have firsthand experience with this card and it SHOULD work with the DVI and at least one DisplayPort using the bundled adapter.  You may possibly just have a bad adapter - it's rare but I've seen plenty in my time.  I've also seen rare issues with the Quadro driver in XP locking out displays - you could try rolling back to a 190 revision.

Comment: monitors are Viewsonic VX922 19" 4:3 LCD with DVI & D-Sub .. I have suspected the DP to DVI may be faulty.

Comment: when you say "rolling back to a 190 version" what 190 version are you referring to.

Comment: I mean an older revision of the Quadro driver from the 19x release series - see http://www.nvidia.com/Download/Find.aspx?lang=en-us, put in appropriate fields, you'll get all old drivers.  I've had luck with 197.03 but you might even try 190.38.